# After downloading a java file it would not open

Tags: java, macos, minecraft-forge

Note: This is on mac

So i downloaded a java file recently and after downloading it i tried opening it to which it says the java jar file cannot be opened and to check to console. After looking up a tutorial i put the following commands into the terminal.

```
Umairs-MacBook-Air:~ umairahmed$ java -version
java version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9-LTS, mixed mode)
Umairs-MacBook-Air:~ umairahmed$ java -jar/Users/umairahmed/Downloads/forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2768-universal.jar 
Unrecognized option: -jar/Users/umairahmed/Downloads/forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2768-universal.jar
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

How do i fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a space

```
java -jar /Users/.......
```